# colormap range using offsetbox

Tags: matplotlib, range, colormap

How can I manually set colormap range when using OffsetImage and AnnotationBbox? The methods are called as following (inside of the loop where I put images instead of 2D points):

```
im = OffsetImage(img, zoom=zoom)
ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (x0, y0), xycoords='data', frameon=False)
artist.append(ax.add_artist(ab))
```

And then, outside of the loop:

```
ax.update_datalim(np.column_stack([x, y]))
ax.autoscale()
```

I am adding the images to the ax, I can specify cmap in OffsetImage, but there is no option for range. And if I try

```
plt.clim(vmin, vmax)
```

the error occurs: RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OffsetImage` packs an image into an offsetbbox.  So, you need to get the child:
`img = im.get_children()[0]; img.set_clim(vmin=0, vmax=3.14)`